# ESLint error: Unexpected assignment within a 'while' statement

Tags: javascript, while-loop, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have a function that formats currency:

```
export const formatDollar = (dollar) => {
  const format = function moneyFormat(val, sign = '$ ') {
    const pieces = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2).split('');
    let ii = pieces.length - 3;
    while ((ii -= 3) > 0) {
      pieces.splice(ii, 0, ',');
    }
    return sign + pieces.join('');
  };
  return format(dollar);
};
```

This part is causing an ESLint error:

`while ((ii -= 3) > 0) {
      pieces.splice(ii, 0, ',');
    }`

> error  Unexpected assignment within a 'while' statement  no-cond-assign

How should i write this statement so that ESLint check passes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression `ii -= 3` is equivalent to `ii = ii - 3` and can be replaced with `ii - 3 > 0`. However, since in this case it doesn't modify variable `ii` anymore. You need to decrement it explicitly in loop. So you could rewrite it like this:

```
while (ii > 3) { // or ii - 3 > 0
  ii = ii - 3;
  pieces.splice(ii, 0, ',');
}
```

Couple of tests:

```js
const formatDollar = (dollar) => {
  const format = function moneyFormat(val, sign = '$ ') {
    const pieces = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2).split('');
    let ii = pieces.length - 3;
    while (ii > 3) {
      ii = ii - 3
      pieces.splice(ii, 0, ',');
    }
    return sign + pieces.join('');
  };
  return format(dollar);
};

console.log(formatDollar(12345678))
console.log(formatDollar(12345))
console.log(formatDollar(12))
console.log(formatDollar(.12))
```